# from Spring Bean xml to Spring Bean Java classes

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, spring-bean

How can I do this in Java classes?

```
    <bean id="rememberMeFilter" class=
     "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
      <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
      <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rememberMeServices" class=
     "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
      <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"/>
      <property name="key" value="some-string"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class=
     "org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
      <property name="key" value="some-string"/>
    </bean>
```

And also disable auto-configuration in Java classes

```
    auto-config="false"
```

Comment: in a configuration file?...

Comment: Yes, that's right. In the config file.

Comment: so what's the question...

Comment: from Spring Bean xml to Spring Bean Java classes

Comment: How do I do this in java classes?

Comment: How can I do the same in Java classes?

Comment: Yes, you should do it in a config file, check this for example https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties

Answer (score 0):

To save time and avoid bugs, I will give a different suggestion. Instead of re-defining all beans using `@Bean`, you can include the whole existing application context .XML file(s) as it is using `@ImportResource` annotation with `@Configuration`/`@SpringBootApplication`.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html